# Install CANopen package in yocto

Tags: yocto, can-bus, canopen, yocto-recipe, imx8

I have tried installing CANopen in yocto using below command. But the CANOpen is not getting installed.

```
bitbake canopensocket_git
```

In local.conf file I had added

```
CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL += " canopensocket_git "
```

How I can install canopen package?

Any input is also considered.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, that's a syntax error `canopensocket_git`.

The recipe name `${PN}` is `canopensocket` and every thing after the`_` is the version number `${PV}`.

So, you need to only specify the recipe name. Or if you have different versions you can specify one by:

```
PREFERRED_VERSION_canopensocket = "version_here"
```

That being said, I found a recipe for `canopensocket` in [here](https://patchwork.openembedded.org/patch/127035/).

But if fails and it is not updated with latest github commit.

I did some modifications on it, here is my recipe:

```
SUMMARY = "Linux CANOpen tools"
DESCRIPTION = "Linux CANOpen Protocol Stack Tools"
LICENSE = "GPLv2"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://gpl-2.0.txt;md5=b234ee4d69f5fce4486a80fdaf4a4263"

SRC_URI = "git://github.com/CANopenNode/CANopenSocket.git"
SRCREV = "ec9735165502e08b5d2e84d641833709b6faeb96"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

do_compile_prepend() {
    cd ${S}
    git submodule init
    git submodule update
}

do_compile() {
    cd ${S}/cocomm
    make
    cd ${S}/canopencgi
    make
}

do_install(){
    install -d ${D}${bindir}
    install -m 0755 ${S}/cocomm/cocomm ${D}${bindir}
    install -m 0755 ${S}/canopencgi/canopen.cgi ${D}${bindir}
}

FILES_${PN} += "${bindir}/*"
```

I modified `do_compile`, `do_install` and added the packaging of `FILES`.

And I set `SRCREV` to the latest v4 tag commit instead of `AUTOREV`.

I do not know what this recipe does, but I compiled it and the build was okay for me on a `zeus` build.

The build produced two binaries: `cocomm` and `canopen.cgi` .

No if you want to install it to your image, add this to you cutom image recipe:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " canopensocket"
```

Comment: I am not able to install canopensocket_git. The files are not available under meta-oe/recipes-extended/canopennode/. I had downloaded the files and copied under meta-oe/recipes-extended/canopennode/. What further changes are to be done?

Comment: Did you run `bitbake canopensocket_git` or `bitbake canopensocket` ?

Comment: I had run ```bitbake canopensocket```

Comment: Can you post the error when you run the command ?